# Multiple Mobilefirst-Server artifacts concurrent deploy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I use a batch procedure for deploying MFP v7 artifacts (wlapps and adapters).
The procedure is based on the standard ant tasks defined in worklight-ant-deployer.jar.

The MFP environment runs onto a WAS cell, and consists of a single AdminService application managing multiple WLRuntimes.

Is it possible to run two (or more) deploy tasks concurrently against different WLRuntime targets ?

Furthermore, sticking to a single WLRuntime, is it possible to deploy different multiple artifacts concurrently ?

Thanks in advance for any answer/comment.
Ciao, Stefano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single WL runtime, all deployments are internally done sequentially. You can start the deployments concurrently, but internally only one deployment is done after the other, due to a transaction locking mechanism. If you start too many deployments in parallel, it may come to timeout situations, even though this is seldom. By default, a deployment transaction waits for 20 minutes before it may time out.

Note: starting deployments in parallel means here using ant tasks or the wladm tool or the REST service directly. In the MobileFirst Admin Console UI, you will see deploy buttons disabled when another deployment transaction is ongoing, hence in the UI, it is not so easily possible to start deployments in parallel. The UI tries to prohibit that.

Note 2: the 20 minutes that I mentioned above is for the locking mechanism itself. Ant/wladm has its own parameters for time out that may be lower, hence in ant tasks, you might get time outs quicker than 20 min. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_invoking_the_wladm_ant_task.html).

For multiple WL runtimes, deployments can be concurrently. The mentioned locking mechanism is per runtime, hence deployments that occur in one WL runtime will not influence any other WL runtime.